# Training Binary Inputs and Outputs data using Tensorflow /Keras

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have bianry inputs and outputs data that I want to train using keras/Tensorflow.
However after training  I still have low accuracy (less than 20%) and my model always predicts a same label for any input.
My dataset Overview :
X                 y
10000011010101 01010100
11100001001101 11100011
10000001110101 01101100
10100101100101 10011001
11101111110101 11011100
01001000001101 10000010
01000110001101 01100010

I must use Bop Optimizer (https://docs.larq.dev/larq/api/optimizers/#bop) from Larq framework not Adam.
I think I don't need to one-hot encode my dataset since it is already binary or I'm wrong ?
My class  model:
class BNN(models.Sequential):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**()

```
    kwargs = dict(
        # input_quantizer="ste_sign",
        kernel_quantizer="ste_sign",
        kernel_constraint="weight_clip",
        use_bias=True,
        bias_initializer='glorot_uniform'
    )

    self.add(QuantDense(14, input_shape=(14,), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', **kwargs))
    self.add(BatchNormalization())
    self.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Experiment with dropout rate

    self.add(QuantDense(14, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', **kwargs))
    self.add(BatchNormalization())
    self.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.add(QuantDense(8, activation='sigmoid', name='linear_layer_output', **kwargs))
```

and my training process :

np.random.seed(42)
def generate_binary_string(x_size, y_size, num_samples):
half_x_size = x_size // 2
half_y_size = y_size // 2
half_samples = num_samples // 2

```
            unique_labels = [''.join(np.random.choice(['0', '1'], size=half_y_size)) for _ in range(2**half_y_size)]

            class_0_X = np.array([[int(char) for char in generate_binary_string(half_x_size)] for _ in range(half_samples)])
            class_1_X = np.array([[int(char) for char in generate_binary_string(half_x_size)] for _ in range(half_samples)])

            class_0_y = np.array([np.array(list(label), dtype=int) for label in np.random.choice(unique_labels, size=half_samples)])
            class_1_y = np.array([np.array(list(label), dtype=int) for label in np.random.choice(unique_labels, size=half_samples)])

            X_balanced = np.concatenate([class_0_X, class_1_X])
            y_balanced = np.concatenate([class_0_y, class_1_y])

            X_balanced, y_balanced = shuffle(X_balanced, y_balanced, random_state=42)
            np.savetxt('balanced_dataset.txt', np.column_stack((X_balanced, y_balanced)), fmt='%d', delimiter=',', header='X, y')


            return X_balanced, y_balanced    



 def generate_binary_string(size):
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(['0', '1'], size=size))

 num_samples = 1000
 #X = np.array([[int(char) for char in generate_binary_string(14)] for _ in range(num_samples)])
 #y = np.array([[int(char) for char in generate_binary_string(8)] for _ in range(num_samples)])
 X, y = generate_binary_string(28, 16, num_samples)
 print('X Shape', X.shape)
 print('y Shape',y.shape)
 check_class_balance(X, y)


 # Normalize the input data
 scaler = StandardScaler()
 X_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(X)

 # Reshape the data for CNN (assuming data represents sequences)
 X_cnn = X_normalized.reshape((X.shape[0], -1))

 # Shuffle the data
 X_cnn, y = shuffle(X_cnn, y, random_state=42)

 n_splits = 5
 kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_cnn, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


 for fold, (train_index, val_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X_cnn)):
    print(f"Training Fold {fold + 1}/{n_splits}")

    X_train_fold, X_val_fold = X_cnn[train_index], X_cnn[val_index]
    y_train_fold, y_val_fold = y[train_index], y[val_index]

    model = BNN()  # Initialize your BNN model here

    opt = larq.optimizers.Bop(threshold=1e-08, gamma=0.001, name="Bop")

    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30, restore_best_weights=True)
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Train the CNN model for the current fold
    cnn_history = model.fit(X_train_fold, y_train_fold, epochs=50, batch_size=30,
                            validation_data=(X_val_fold, y_val_fold), verbose=1,
                            callbacks=[early_stopping])
    cnn_loss, cnn_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    print(f"Fold {fold + 1} - CNN Test Loss: {cnn_loss:.4f}")
    print(f"Fold {fold + 1} - CNN Test Accuracy: {cnn_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
```